# Fabric.JS scaleToWidth not working for text items and resulting in different width then set

Tags: fabricjs

I try to set a defined width for a text object by below code (excerpt) but get a different width instead. e.g. "size to be 200" and "new size after render 202.25..." as differences. What am I missing or is this a bug?

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  
var size = 200;
var color = "#ff0000";
var fontScale = 1;

console.log("size to be "+size);
    
    var opt = {
             fill: color,
             stroke: color,
             scaleX: fontScale,
             scaleY: fontScale,
             fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
             fontSize: 40,
             fontWeight: "",
             fontStyle: "",
             textAlign: "center"
          }
    var itext = new fabric.Text("Hallo", opt);
    canvas.add(itext);
    itext.scaleToWidth(size);
    canvas.renderAll();    
    console.log("new size after render "+itext.getScaledWidth());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tomfree/drcqpwxy/4/

Comment: Note: As a workaround I figured out that   console.log("factor: "+itext.getScaledWidth()/size); is a constant and thus I know what factor to apply to sizze before using scaleToWidth to get required results. It's weird still and I would appreciate a proper solution instead of this hack